# Typescript thinks this function would come to an end

Tags: typescript

Imagine the following code:

```js
class MyThrowable {

    // This function will never return, the throw statement is the only one inside of it...
    throw(msg: string):never {
        throw new Error(msg);
    }
}

class SuperThrowable extends MyThrowable {

    // This function does not explicitly throw, but implicitly 
    throw(msg: string):never { 
        super.throw(msg);
    }
}
```

TypeScript throws the following error, regardless of the things mentioned in the code:

> A function returning 'never' cannot have a reachable end point.(2534)

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ts=3.8.0-dev.20200110&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=2#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeAVAFgJwPYHcwCMQFNoBvAWAChzoroB6G6FASxgDMBXAO2ABdH0PomRiBDQO+AG75U0VPm5tUHADTRuyQuoyZoEbmG74Atvg7dozNRuj8Q8G+IsDG3AHTvK1LVgAURiADmAFy63KiMHAEAlEHiUjKkZNTJVtpi+DoAoqgYqH6BUQDcnlQAvuTlFGSgkDAAymwADtIo2rgE0PgAHoYcACYwCK1Y7YSJJbT0TKycPHwCfej4MBzo5t2NIIzALnapWKo4bOaMRpvbu-YT3pj5waHhkTFx0sTQE8kQTdKuN3dFE0qpSAA)

Am I missing something?
The [TS docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never) say:

> [...] never is the return type for a function expression or an arrow function expression that always throws an exception or one that never returns [..]

And this is obviously the case, the super method throws an error and therefore the end of the "child-class" will never get reached, another example which is basically the same but works:

```js
class Throwable {
    sayHello(msg: string): string {
        return "Hello"
    }
}

class SuperThrowable extends Throwable {
    throw(msg: string):string { 
        return super.sayHello(msg);
    }
}
```

This time it's a string, and apparently ts manages to properly resolve the type...

I tried searching for things like *TS fails to resolve never as return type*, *typescript never as return-type not working on calls to superclass* or *typescript superclass never return type* but without success...

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a TS bug. In TS 3.7 we got ["better support for never returning functions"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#better-support-for-never-returning-functions) which considers functions that return `never` in control flow analysis.

Prior to TS 3.7, you would have had to `return neverReturningFunction()` for the code to type check. PR [#32695](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32695) added support for just calling the function.

- If you use `return super.throw(msg)` there is no compiler error.
- If you call a standalone function, there is no compiler error.
- If you call a method returning `never` on `this`, there is no compiler error.

There is [a comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32695#discussion_r310360637) on the PR asking about methods on `this` and `super`, but it doesn't have a confirmation if this should be supported or not. Given the last bullet, it seems like it should be supported and this is a bug, especially since this is still a compiler error! I've opened [#36147](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36147) with a report.